# Different scrolling behavior on different children in CollapsingTollbarLayout

Tags: android, scroll, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have CollapsingToolbarLayout in AppBarLayout with RelativeLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">




            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <include android:id="@+id/post_meta"
                         layout="@layout/item_post_meta_layout"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="100dp"
                         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                         app:layout_collapseMode="none"
                         app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
                />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@id/post_meta"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:minHeight="292dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                    />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

As you can see, in RelativeLayout 2 children, and I want to make different behavior while scrolling:
When scroll up, my layout (id=post_meta) scroll under image and image pinned to Toolbar. Is it possible? And if so, how can I make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found out solution and made it this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="460dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="460dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            />

            <include android:id="@+id/post_meta"
                     layout="@layout/item_post_meta_layout"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                     app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|exitUntilCollapsed"
            />


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="340dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/post_pager"
                    layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="340dp"/>

                <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                    android:id="@+id/circlePageInd"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    app:fillColor="#E0E0E0"
                    app:pageColor="#FFF"
                    app:radius="2dp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="50dp"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/chat_rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:minHeight="100dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/send_container"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So, here post_meta layout scrolling under RelativeLayout with ViewPager when scrolling up and scrolling out of RelativeLayout with ViewPager after RelativeLayout scrolled down.